# How can load a request in a method of groovy bean?

Tags: groovy, soapui

I want to create a groovy's bean which takes the parameters of a request and return an appropriate response when the sum of parameter is positive. I want to know how I can load my request in a method of groovy bean

```
import com.eviware.soapui.support.XmlHolder
import com.eviware.soapui.support.GroovyUtils
import com.eviware.soapui.model.mock.*
import org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils
import groovy.util.*
import groovy.lang.*

public class Test
{
    public int somme ()
    {
        def holder = new XmlHolder(mockRequest.getRequestContent())
        def a = holder["//firstInt:a"]
        def b = holder["//secondInt:b"]
        return(a + b)
    }

    public String getResponse ()
    {
        Test t = new Test ()
        if (t.somme() > 0)
        {
            return "response1"
        }
        else
        {
           return "response2"
        }
    }
  }
```

When I run this code I have error below:

> com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.mock.DispatchException: Failed to
>   dispatch using script; groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such
>   property: mockRequest for class:Test

Comment: Well, what's `mockRequest`? Where is it supposed to come from?

Comment: It is supposed to come from Mockservice generated with SoapUI

Comment: My goal is to instanciate Test's class in another script.

Comment: But where is it being *defined*? You can't access arbitrary things inside classes; it needs to be passed in, injected, global, a static method, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Your class is supposed to appear like this.

Note the changes:

1. Declared `mockRequest` member variable, pass it as argument to constructor of the class.
2. Object creation is not required in `getResponse()` method, instead you may do it in another script as you desired. Like in Mock response's script where `mockRequest` is available.

```groovy
import com.eviware.soapui.model.mock.MockRequest 
import com.eviware.soapui.support.XmlHolder 
public class Test {
  MockRequest mockRequest 
  public Test(MockRequest mockRequest) {
    this.mockRequest=mockRequest
  }
  public int somme () {
    def holder=new XmlHolder(mockRequest.getRequestContent()) 
    def a=holder["//firstInt:a"] 
    def b=holder["//secondInt:b"] 
    (a + b)
  }
  public String getResponse () {
    somme() ? "response1" : "response2"
  }
}
```